# Python - get results of one item based on another in list

Tags: python, json, list

```
 [       
 {
    "account" : "",
    "address" : "D8xWhR8LqSdSLTxRWwouQ3EiSnvcjLmdo6",
    "category" : "send",
    "amount" : -1000.00000000,
    "fee" : -0.00000001,
    "confirmations" : 716,
    "blockhash" : "4569322b4c8c98fba3ef4c7bda91b53b4ee82d268eae2ff7658bc0d3753c00ff",
    "blockindex" : 2,
    "blocktime" : 1394242415,
    "txid" : "45b629a779e6e0bf6d160c37833a27f1f2cc1bfa34632d166cccae83e69eb6fe",
    "time" : 1394242259,
    "timereceived" : 1394242259
    },
    {
    "account" : "",
    "address" : "DCPFe1fs7qScDFvoTexYqo95LmnJJkjmu7",
    "category" : "receive",
    "amount" : 0.13370000,
    "confirmations" : 717,
    "blockhash" : "e9024e177b42ca23fed741fb90c39836de5f9c722a93157e50df2e3f2c318d77",
    "blockindex" : 26,
    "blocktime" : 1394242412,
    "txid" : "ce41b4c35b09ae582436b8138d62375840c32bd9ea0360457bd9f589012d2da3",
    "time" : 1394242315,
    "timereceived" : 1394242315
    },
    {
    "account" : "",
    "address" : "DCPFe1fs7qScDFvoTexYqo95LmnJJkjmu7",
    "category" : "receive",
    "amount" : 0.00100000,
    "confirmations" : 692,
    "blockhash" : "17eb2ef40b8bcb2ceb3d7f07d6545f03fc9bf41c8d28f759becd84a31e65e123",
    "blockindex" : 14,
    "blocktime" : 1394243788,
    "txid" : "2b099fd0ce6239c5c3c69e2ba70669c3069858908e42b8ca970bf213e555d715",
    "time" : 1394243669,
    "timereceived" : 1394243669
    },
    {
    "account" : "",
    "address" : "DCPFe1fs7qScDFvoTexYqo95LmnJJkjmu7",
    "category" : "send",
    "amount" : -0.00100000,
    "fee" : -2.00000000,
    "confirmations" : 692,
    "blockhash" : "17eb2ef40b8bcb2ceb3d7f07d6545f03fc9bf41c8d28f759becd84a31e65e123",
    "blockindex" : 14,
    "blocktime" : 1394243788,
    "txid" : "2b099fd0ce6239c5c3c69e2ba70669c3069858908e42b8ca970bf213e555d715",
    "time" : 1394243669,
    "timereceived" : 1394243669
    }
    ]
```

That ^^ is my data.

How am I able to see the entries in "txid" where the "category" == "receive" I also wish to write this line by line to a file called "list.txt"

I'm not interested at all in where "category" == "send"

Thanks :-)

EDIT:
This is my code

```
with (open('text.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
my_list = json.load(open("text.json"))
result = sum(item["category"] == "receive" for item in my_list)

i = 0
res = ""
while i < result:
    res = data[i]['txid']
    if data[i]['category'] == "receive":
        with open ("list.txt", "a") as myfile:
            myfile.write(res + "\n")
i += 1
```

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow is not a provide me the code service. Please show us what you have tried, and we would be more than happy to help you in the right direction.

Comment: For starters, take this into a local variable, and parse through the values in a for loop. in the loop, you would check for `data.get('category') == 'receive'` .

Comment: Quite a few places that look like typos to me. You might want to test the code at lease to the point where you no longer get SyntaxError.

Comment: Sorry, I should have fixed it now. I don't have copy + paste working through my vm yet so I had to type it out. Should be OK now.

Comment: As written, your code runs forever because the last line "i += 1" is after the while loop. It needs to be indented another level. Then the problem is that you have a list of 4 items, you've identified that 2 of them are receives, then your while loop goes through 2 times. It finds the first thing which isn't a receive, the second thing which is a receive, then it stops. Instead of counting receives, remove `result =` line and run the loop over the whole list `while i<len(my_list):`. Also you open and load the file twice and don't need to. It's not standard Python still, but it works then.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm still a bit new to python but am getting the hang of it quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
object_list = json.load(open('text.json'))

receive_txids = [(x['txid'] + '\n') for x in object_list if x['category'] == 'receive']

output_file = open("list.txt", "a")
output_file.writelines(receive_txids)
```

Edit, here's a longer but clearer (untested) version:

```
import json

with open('text.json') as json_file:
    object_list = json.load(json_file)

receive_txids = []
for object in object_list:
    if object['category'] == 'receive':
        receive_txids.append(object['txid'])

with open("list.txt", "a") as output_file:
    for txid in receive_txids:
        output_file.write(txid + '\n')
```

Edit: Why am I even building up a list and then doing nothing much with it?
With no intermediate list, the terse version:

```
import json
object_list = json.load(open('text.json'))

output_file = open("list.txt", "a")
output_file.writelines([(x['txid'] + '\n') for x in object_list if x['category'] == 'receive'])
```

and the tidier, clearer version:

```
import json

with open('text.json') as json_file:
    object_list = json.load(json_file)

with open("list.txt", "a") as output_file:
    for object in object_list:
        if object['category'] == 'receive':
            output_file.writeline(object['txid'] + '\n')
```